# How to set up webhooks individually for each site in multi-site configuration with many customers?

Tags: plugin-development, filter, multi-site, plugin-webhooks

The current issue is that I have multi-site setup, where are many different sites in a single Craft instance, e.g., I have 10 websites from 10 customers, when one customer updates his website I want Webhook to be triggered only for his website, not all 10 sites at once. How could I achieve this, is there a filter where I can do it like `{{event.site.name == "someSite2Handle"}}` in a debouncer or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using multi-site for 10 different customers doesn't sound like what it is intended to be used for. But regardless, assuming you are using the [Webhooks plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/webhooks), you can create your own additional filter that checks for the site ID you are interested in.

```php
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\webhooks\Plugin as Webhooks;
use craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent;

Event::on(
    Webhooks::class, 
    Webhooks::EVENT_REGISTER_FILTER_TYPES, 
    function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
        $event->types[] = SiteFilter::class;
    }
);
```

```php
use Craft;
use craft\webhooks\filters\FilterInterface;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use yii\base\Event;

class SiteFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public static function displayName(): string
    {
        return 'Entry is in site with ID 1';
    }

    public static function show(string $class, string $event): bool
    {
        return $class === Entry::class;
    }

    public static function check(Event $event, bool $value): bool
    {
        $entry = $event->sender;

        return ($entry->siteId == 1) === $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The check methods is not working. I've done this instead :
 $entry = $event->sender;
 return ($entry->siteId == 1) === $value;

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer accordingly.